# REST Resources, should they be client specific, server specific or both?

Tags: rest

I have a use case where for a same entity, there are 2 identifiers, and each of them can map to the entity if used separately. 1 identifier is client friendly (say c_id), and the other is server friendly (say s_id). Clients do know the s_id, but in most cases they wont use it. And server knows both the ids, but the implementation on server is such that every thing is easily mapped using s_id.
In such a case, is it a good practice to provide resources on both c_id & s_id level, where the resource name and id (in input) will differ and will do the same thing, or should it be only a single resource, which also leads to the debate that which resource should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally have the resources existing under their server identities, and then provide search methods that return 302 redirects (or 307 if you prefer) to the appropriate resources. The clients would use these search/query methods to arrive at the correct resources.

Because the server "owns" the resources (and their URLs), it's fine for it to arrive at the resources by URL-fiddling. Whereas, because the clients shouldn't engage in URL-fiddling to find resources, giving them a query method where they can specify the ID(s) they know as query string parameters feels cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Your API exists for the benefit of its users. You should always strive to make it as easy as possible for them. If unique client-friendly IDs exist for all resources, then make your API work against the client-friendly ID. Your API can store a map from clientId to serverId in memory and easily switch to the ID it's more comfortable with.

If there aren't unique client-friendly IDs for all resources, you've got a pickle. I'd start by trying to close the gap (ie give the remaining resources clientIds). If that's not an option, then I agree with Damien.

Answer (score 0):

What I often do is create the canonical URI as the one with the `s_id`, so something like,

```
http://example.org/api/foo/{s_id}
```

and then provide a search facility that allows searching by `c_id`, and potentially other attributes.

```
http://examples.org/api/foos?c_id={c_id}
```

This can return a list of foos, each with a link to the `s_id` URI.  Or if, as in your case, only one foo returns, then you could either redirect to the canonical URI, or you can actually return the full foo representation and set the Content-Location header to the canonical URI.